# JS Controller call parent in callback?

Tags: javascript, inheritance, extjs

I have a controller that is extended by a a childcontroller. This child needs needs to display an element first and after that raise the overriden parent function. Here is my abstracted code:

```
Ext.define('ParentController', {

    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',

    //lot of code
    myFunction(){
         //....
         this.getSomething();

    }
}
```

and then there is a controller extending this existing one:

```
Ext.define('ChildController', {
    extend: ParentController,
    onlyChildFunction(dummy){
        //create element
        ...
       element.onClosed = function(){
           dummy();
       }

       return element;
    }

    //override
    myFunction(){
        //this.callParent();
        var element = onlyChildFunction( this.self.superclass.myFunction() );
        element.show();
}
```

Passing the superclass function doesn't work because the ParentController is using a lot of references to a instance of ParentController (this).

I don't want to copy the code from ParentController directly, because it would mean to maintain the same function twice. One way could be to call myFunction() on element.onClosed again and make some kind of flag there only to do a callParent(). But this sounds ugly - any better suggestions?

Thanks in advance - help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, onlyChildFunction must be passed a Function. (Here, you are passing the return value of calling the parent class's `myFunction`.)

Would something like this work ?

```
Ext.define("ChildController", {

  ...

  myFunction : function () {
    var that = this;
    var element = onlyChildFunction( function () {
       that.self.superclass.myFunction()
    });
    ...
  }
}
```

The idea being that you pass a function that calls the "parent" function in the right context.
In which case, you *might* be able to use the [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) function to the same effect :

```
var element = onlyChildFunction(this.self.superclass.myFunction.bind(this));
```

But I'm not sure what the this / self / superclass values are in your case...